# Need help speeding up seaborn heatmap to png in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I have some code that will load data, enrich it, perform certain statistical analysis, and eventually generate heatmaps. The data on which these heatmaps are based are small pivot tables (i.e. not too many rows and columns), but I'm sure the seaborn heatmap generation is what makes my code so slow.

I've tried different methods for clearing one or several plots, updating my version of seaborn, nothing seams to help speed this up.

This is my first effort at generating heatmaps. Is seaborn heatmap generation always slow or is there anything I can optimize in my code? (keep in mind, this code is in a for loop that's a few hundred loops long...but the dataframe of data in each loop is small

Thanks for any help you can provide! I saw some similar questions but nothing that's worked so far so any help is appreciated

```
    ax = sns.heatmap(
        heatmap_data,
        annot=True,
        annot_kws={"size": 30},
        fmt="g",
        )
        fig.savefig(graph_path)
    
    matplotlib.pyplot.clf()
```

Comment: Can you be more precise with what you mean by `not too many rows and columns`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. On average I would say there are around 20-30 columns and 5-20 (usually around 10) rows on every loop, and there are likely around ~400 loops. I was thinking using numpy arrays would be faster but I need the labels provided by the dataframe

Comment: I guess the issue is more related to matplotlib plot optimization when there are hundreds of graphs to generate and export...I'm still a bit of a beginner so I don't know if storing the plots in a list or a generator will help speed things up or not...any visualization experts out there?

Comment: The annotation text is very likely the slow part here. Text in matplotlib is, in general, pretty slow, and you're adding ~300 separate text objects per plot.